# How does VS code completion work in this situation?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently I was watching a YouTube channel programming video and was copying the code to my workspace of Visual Studio Code. Surprisingly the code completion suggested to me while typing was exactly the same as I was seeing in the video.

[image: Code completion]

I am curious as to how does Vs code predict the exact same code from the video?

Comment: It looks like you have copilot active. And maybe the one who created the video also used copilot to create the code shown in the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using [GitHub Copilot](https://github.com/features/copilot), a code completion/suggestion tool which offers snippets of code based on other code that it has seen in its training dataset. The code in the video likely appears verbatim in the training dataset, since either the author or other people who have followed the tutorial in the same video may have posted it online.

Comment: @starball The question includes a screenshot with "accept" and "accept word" hints, which matches what Copilot looks like according to Google image search. I don't see any results for Tabnine which look the same. However, I don't use either tool so I am only going by what it looks like in screenshots I found by searching, hence my answer beginning "It looks like ...".